# When to use Dimensional Point vs Trie types

Tags: solr

I have recently upgraded to Solr 6.6.0 and I'm wondering about [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/putting-the-pieces-together.html#choosing-appropriate-numeric-types):

> For general numeric needs, consider using one of the`IntPointField`,
>   LongPointField, FloatPointField, or DoublePointField classes,
>   depending on the specific values you expect. These "Dimensional Point"
>   based numeric classes use specially encoded data structures to support
>   efficient range queries regardless of the size of the ranges used.
>   Enable DocValues on these fields as needed for sorting and/or
>   faceting.
>
> ***Some Solr features may not yet work with "Dimensional Points"***, in
>   which case you may want to consider the equivalent TrieIntField,
>   TrieLongField, TrieFloatField, and TrieDoubleField classes.

So... which Solr features don't work with point types exactly?

I'd like to use the point types, but I'd like to know what will break when switching from trie field types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [to the PointType implementation issue on the jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8396), the following related tickets are still open:

- SOLR-10939 JoinQParser gives incorrect results with numeric PointFields
- SOLR-11023 Need SortedNumerics/Points version of EnumField
- SOLR-10556 query-time scoring join for Point-based numeric fields
- SOLR-9985 LukeRequestHandler doesn’t populate docFreq for PointFields
- SOLR-9988 Add method toInternalByteRef to FieldType and possibly deprecate tointeral

Seeing as the original issue has been closed you can safely assume that all major features work as expected.